# (De)Serialize abstract class with Gson

Tags: java, polymorphism, gson

So currently, I'm trying to find a way to (de)serialize my data so the Map will be able to contain instances of Wagon and not just Component. Is there any way to do this with my current structure of objects?

```
class Standplaats {
   String id;
   Map<String, Trein> treinen;
}

class Trein {
   String id;
   Map<String, Component> componenten;
}

abstract class Component {
   String id;
}

class Wagon extends Component {
   int seats;
}

//serializing
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
List<Standplaats> list = new ArrayList<>(standplaatsen.size());
standplaatsen.forEach((id, standplaats) -> list.add(standplaats));
String toJson = gson.toJson(list);

//deserializing
Standplaats[] standplaatsen = GSON.fromJson(br, Standplaats[].class);
```

The json is currently looking like this:

```
{
"id": "standplaats1",
"treinen": {
  "trein1": {
    "id": "trein1",
    "componenten": {
      "wagon1": {
        "seats": 20,
        "id": "wagon1"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you declared it as `Map<String, Component>`? Declaring it as `Map<String, Wagon>` would probably work without any changes

Comment: it's for the expandability for the application, there will be multiple sub-types of Component eventually.